# Accelerating Electrons

Tags: electrons, acceleration

If I was trying to accelerate an electron in a vacuum, if at anode A the voltage is say 10 kV, and then if there was a second anode (B), and anode B has a voltage of 10 kV as well, would the electron accelerate further from anode A to anode B?
or since the voltage is the same, the speed would remain constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no electric field between two conducting plates that are at the same potential.

If there is no field, there is no electrical force on the electrons.

If there is no force, there is no acceleration.